# Why were Treasury interest rates 3-4% in 1999-2000, 2007-2008, but merely 0.6-0.7% now?

Tags: interest-rate

[rymor comments on Is there a Tech bubble forming?](https://old.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/comments/ilnn3z/is_there_a_tech_bubble_forming/g3tmp1i/)

> The fact that 10 year treasury rates were 3-4% during the booms in 1999/2000 and 2007-8 is a big difference IMO. Now, you can’t get more than 0.2% in a CD and LT treasures are less than a percent, with risk of rate movement and inflation. Asset prices across all classes are inflated, including gold. So there is no alternative to securities with any yield.

Why didn't the Federal Reserve slash interest rates in 1999-2000 and 2007-2008 as they are doing now?

Correct this if I'm wrong, but the title refers to the [red interest rates below](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/textview.aspx?data=yield).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this chart you can see the federal funds rate was cut to supply reserves at lower rates in the 2000, 2008, and 2020 recessions. This is the rate at which banks lend to each other overnight and that the Federal Reserve can influence by agreeing to lend and take collateral with a short term agreement to reverse the loan.

[image: FFR]

The 10 year Treasury bond yield which you have quoted is determined by private market participants although the Federal Reserve can also participate but in recent history the Fed had an intention to purchase or sell a certain amount for example each month which is not the same as saying they will transact at a certain price that by arithmetic means a certain yield.

For example here is description of a promise that covers the period of Nov 2010 to mid-2011.

> In November 2010, the FOMC announced that it would further expand the
> Federal Reserve's security holdings by purchasing an additional $600
> billion of longer-term Treasury securities over a period ending in
> mid-2011.

That quote is from this source...
[Link to a Ben Bernanke talk given on August 31, 2012.](https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/bernanke20120831a.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> Why didn't the Federal Reserve slash interest rates in 1999-2000 and 2007-2008 as they are doing now?

The Fed cut rates after it was aware of recessionary risks. (The recession associated with the Financial Crisis is dated as starting in December 2007, but many observers were not convinced the dip in activity was significant until the Lehman crisis.) The Fed was well aware of the recession that started in 2020, and so cut rates.

The Fed sets rates based on conditions in the real economy and the credit system, it does not set rates based on what tech stocks are doing.